# Problem iterating through list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I am working with a database of three-dimensional vectors and am trying to calculate the surface area of the triangles between all possible combinations of three vectors. The goal is to get a list or dataframe containing the area for all possible combinations, each named based on the column names of the respective coordinates (e. g. c1:c2:c3).

For the moment, I get "invalid subscript type 'list'" as an error when running my function for the triangle calculation but I don't know how else to iterate through my list.

I am generating a list of all possible combinations of coordinates using combn

```
tridf <- combn(newdata, 3, simplify=FALSE) #newdata contains the coordinates, each column consists of a three-dimensional vector with x, y and z
```

Example for structure of newdata:

```
 |    c1    |    c2    |    c3    |    c4    |    c5    |
x| -8.99    | -8.71    | -10.52   | -8.38    | -55.76   |
y| -267.54  | -266.50  | -266.26  | -279.47  | -243.53  |
z| -117.85  | -122.87  | -200.95  | -146.96  | -130.40  |
```

dput(newdata):

```
    structure(list(g = c("-8.993426322937012", "-267.54718017578125", 
"-117.85099792480469"), n = c("-8.717547416687012", "-266.50799560546875", 
"-122.87059020996094"), ale = c("-10.52885627746582", "-266.2621154785156", 
"-200.95721435546875"), rhi = c("-8.382125854492188", "-279.47918701171875", 
"-146.96658325195312"), fmo.r = c("-55.76047897338867", "-243.5348663330078", 
"-130.4052734375")), row.names = c("V2", "V3", "V4"), class = "data.frame")
```

which gives me a list of n dataframes through which I now would like to iterate using the following function:

```
triarea <- function(i){ 
  newtridf <- as.data.frame(tridf[[i]])
  ab <- as.numeric(newtridf[,2])-as.numeric(newtridf[,1])
  ac <- as.numeric(newtridf[,3])-as.numeric(newtridf[,1])
  c <- as.data.frame(cross(ab,ac)) #cross is a function of library(pracma)
  area <- 0.5*sqrt(c[1,]^2+c[2,]^2+c[3,]^2)
}
```

When running this code manually outside the function there is no problem and I always end up with the correct result for *area*, but when running this as a function, called using combn

```
newcombn <- combn(tridf, 1, triarea, simplify=FALSE)
```

it throws the following error:

> Error in tridf[[i]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

I've been searching the web and trying around for hours now but I am completely lost, especially as I am relatively new to R and programming in general. I get that there seems to be a problem with the data being stored in a list, but I do not know how to approach solving this or how to directly refer iteratively to the respective column of the dataframe inside of the list of dataframes, without the need for auxiliary elements like *newtridf* ...

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help!

Comment: function triarea expects a numeric argument "i". However in your last line `combn(tridf, 1, triarea, simplify=FALSE)` triarea is receiving a list with element (since the number of elements is set to 1). I do not understand why you must use combn in the last line instead of `sapply(seq_along(tridf), triarea)`

Comment: @Ric Villalba Thanks for your answer! There is another, similarily structured function in my script using combn so I thought that's the way to go in this case, too. 

sapply works great and achieves exactly what I needed, thanks! You just saved my day :)

Comment: do no forget to use "seq_along" to get a numeric sequence the length of your list, whether your function expects a numeric index.